# How to run 'quit command' for terminal from PyCharm? For Mac

Tags: python, macos, pycharm

How can I run command for terminal from PyCharm?

For example, next command:

```
osascript -e 'quit app "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"'
```

No problem to run it from terminal, but because of the quotation marks I receive error in PyCharm.
I wrote next:

```
os.system ('osascript -e 'quit app "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"'')
```

And failed.

Is there any solution?

Comment: `And failed.` please edit your question to show how you know it failed. What happened, and what did you expect?

Comment: `F-strings` will make you life easier. https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/f-string-formatting-in-python

Comment: Problem was solved! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the string in """(3 double quotes)
e.g.

```py
"""osascript -e 'quit app "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"'"""
```

Comment: @Vas23Vewe please press the tick to accept this answer if you found it helpful